# W3 and WCAG requirements collide on attributes disallowed to be false

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wcag

[According to W3](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes), we should not use *false* but rather omit the attribute all together. Also, [according to W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/accordion/accordion.html), when toggling parts of the accordion, the *aria-expanded* is toggled between *true* and *false*.

To me, it sounds as a oxymoron and I'd like to get a pointer on how to design the control according to both the W3 guidelines and to WCAG requirements.

One approach is to declare that *aria-anything* is excluded from the *true or nothing* paradigm. Another one would be perahps setting an attribute such as *folded* and *expanded* with no value, simply knowing that the one is negation of the other.

Is any of them accpetable and embraces both W3 and WCAG? Are there alternative best-practice approaches?

Comment: It's not at all a collision or an oxymoron. The `aria-expanded` attribute is not a "Boolean attribute" according to the definition from the first link.

Comment: So, to elaborate for the weak-minded like myself. You are saying that the *false* in *aria-expanded=**false*** isn't actually a boolean value of falsity but rather a string, simply a text that unfortunately happens to be spelled similarly, hence rendering an counter-intuitive experience. Correct? While I believe you and accept the statement, I wonder if there's a blog you could refer to that says so explicitly (in case there's lack of acceptance among a bigger crowd).

Comment: I am not saying anything about the value at all. If you go to [the list of Attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#attributes-3) provided by the W3, you'll see that some of them are noted as "Boolean attribute"s. It's term of art in the specification that also has a common-sense meaning. Apparently the common-sense meaning is preventing the understanding of the specific meaning used in the specification.

Comment: `aria-expanded` is tristate. It has values true, false and undefined. The undefined value is the default and means that the element/control is not expandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [**Boolean attribute** is a specific "microsyntax" in HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes). As you noted, there are certain rules around their usage:

> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

There are only certain attributes which use this microsyntax. These can be found in the HTML 5 specification in the [Attribute index](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/index.html#attributes-1), where the Value column notes that it is a "Boolean attribute". Commonly used examples are `disabled`, `readonly` and `async`.

The `aria-expanded` attribute, while it accepts true and false, is not defined as conforming to the Boolean attribute microsyntax. It is [defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-expanded) under a different specification than HTML 5, the [Accessible Rich Internet Applications (WAI-ARIA)](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) specification. It is actually referred to as [a `state` in that specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#states_and_properties), not an attribute, and can have the value true, false, or undefined.

Comment: great answer, even items that are 'boolean' such as `aria-atomic` are referred to as 'properties' not 'attributes' (https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#statevsprop) and are not valid using microsyntax - you must state "true" or "false" (or as I just found out just `=true` and `=false` are valid which surprised me! That will save me some key strokes!)  I think it is the same convention as `data-` attributes but I cannot find the information on why hyphenated attributes are different, if you have that information I would find it interesting!.

Comment: Hyphens don't have any special meaning; the ARIA folk used `aria-` to avoid namespace collisions since they wanted to allow its use not only in HTML, but in XML and other scenarios.

Comment: As far as `=true` vs `="true"`. It is indeed legal to omit quotes around attributes, but only when the value does not have spaces in it.